# Shading an object based on the distance from an empty

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I am having a shading problem that I cannot seem to figure out. Maybe someone here can help me! :)

I am representing a map with cube array. I made the mesh with geometry nodes (1st screen capture). I'd like to mark the place of a city on a map by shading some of the cubes with emission shader. The more cubes should be emitting the closer to a city center they are. I am trying to achieve this using an empty object and counting the distance from each cube to that empty. I am mixing some random values here to add more organic feel to the end result.

The problem however is that I cannot seem to find a way to shade entire cubes but instead I get cubes that have both emission and diffuse material on them (2nd screen capture). I think the problem has to do with the way I am calculating distance from the empty but despite lots of trying I cannot find the way to do that.

Hopefully my explanation makes sense. Thank you so much for your help!

Tuomas

[image: Geometry node setup]

[image]

Comment: just a hint: you will attract more (lazy) people if you provide a blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything